# Get n Characters from String specified in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Let s = "%2ABCDE" - get first 2 characters from string
then output should be "AB".
Need to get characters from string specified by numeral in string.
E.g. s1="%12ABCDERTYUIOPLKHGF" - get first 12 characters from string.

I tried to get digit using re.findall('\d+', string ), but this creates problem if my string would be "%2ABCD1".
Please suggest

Comment: You want to strip off non-alphebetical characters from the beginning before getting the AB characters?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried re.findall('\d+', string ), but this returns only single digits.

Comment: @user892077 please include what you tried in your question.

Comment: `''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', s)[:2])`

Comment: Just .strip("%")

Comment: @It_is_Chris this doesn't answer the user's question

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp how so, Per OP - "Let s = "%2ABCDE" - get first 2 characters from string then output should be "AB"" I assume it is pretty self explanatory to replace the 2 with `int(re.findall('\d+', s1)[0])`

Comment: @It_is_Chris and if s = "%12ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", then get the first **12** characters.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp correct, as I said I assume it is pretty self explanatory to replace the 2 with `int(re.findall('\d+', s1)[0])` therefore the solution would be `''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', s1)[:int(re.findall('\d+', s1)[0])])`

Answer (score 2):

```py
s = "%2ABCDE"
number = ""
offset = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == "%":
        continue
    elif s[i].isdigit():
        number += s[i]
    else:
        offset = i
        break

print(s[offset:int(number) + offset])
```

Output: `AB`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing this would be to do the following:

```
txt = "%2ABCDE"
number_list = [s for s in txt if s.isdigit()]
number_concate = int("".join(number_list))
txt_filtered = txt[len(number_list)+1:]
print(txt_filtered[:number_concate])
```

Outputs `AB` for string `"%2ABCDE"`

Outputs `ABCDERTYUIOP` for string `"%12ABCDERTYUIOPLKHGF"`

You are taking your string, doing a list comprehension of the string if the digit exists, then joining the list and changing this to an integer to allow for you to filter your string accordingly. Then you strip the string to only the characters and you have your answer printed out.

Comment: But this ***doesn't work*** if the string would be "%2ABCD1" (Please look at this example on the *question*).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
s = '%2ABCDERTYUIOPLKHGF'
numeral_instruction = re.search(r'%\d+',s).group(0)
start = len(numeral_instruction)
stop = start + int(numeral_instruction[1:])
s[start:stop]
```

outputs

```
AB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the first non-digit character in the string (skipping the %) and use that as the basis to get the length and form a substring:

```
s1="%12ABCDERTYUIOPLKHGF"

i = next(i for i,c in enumerate(s1[1:],1) if not c.isdigit())
result = s1[i:i+int(s1[1:i])]

print(result)
ABCDERTYUIOP
```

If the first number in the string is not always at index 1, you can skip a variable number of characters using the same technique:

```
s1="*:%12ABCDERTYUIOPLKHGF"

start = next(i for i,c in enumerate(s1) if c.isdigit())           
end   = next(i for i,c in enumerate(s1[start:],start) if not c.isdigit())
result = s1[end:end+int(s1[start:end])]

print(result)
ABCDERTYUIOP
```

If you want to use the re module, you only need the first occurrence of a number, so use re.search() instead of re.findall():

```
import re
m      = re.search(r"\d+",s1)
result = s1[m.end():m.end()+int(m.group())]

print(result)
ABCDERTYUIOP
```